# What are the Disadvantages of Early Binding?

Tags: c++

[Early binding vs. late binding: what are the comparative benefits and disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367411/early-binding-vs-late-binding-what-are-the-comparative-benefits-and-disadvantag)........

i didn't find any thing which can help me..

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually think of a language that uses early-binding as being disadvantaged in any way.  I guess one disadvantage of early-binding is that you are less flexible at execution-time for things like metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1):

Read the second answer, I think these quotes from it are important:

> there's been one huge advantage of late binding: the malleability/maintainability/extensibility you've mentioned.
>
> ...
> Ease of development is a big deal. It minimizes expensive programmer time -- and the larger your development team, the more significant it becomes. You'd need to balance that against the flexibility you get with late-binding languages.

Hardware is cheap compared to programmer time (Especially over time, as programmer costs increase, hardware only gets cheaper).

If you've only been doing smaller programs where you can plan everything easily beforehand, then there is not a big difference, but once you get a larger program composed of many components, the increase of flexibility using late binding becomes very apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding facilitates more flexible and extensible software
architectures, e.g.,
– Not all design decisions need to be known during the initial stages
of system development
 i.e., they may be postponed until run-time
– Complete source code is not required to extend the system
 i.e., only headers & object code
 This aids both flexibility & extensibility
– Flexibility = ‘easily recombine existing components into new
configurations’
– Extensibility = “easily add new components”

but early binding wont......