# How to select distinct values from one column in adodb recordset Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, recordset

I have a `ADODB.Recordset rs` that I'm getting from DB. I have to reuse this recordset twice now.

This is sample of my Recordset:

```
Mike     Client
John     Manager
Karen    Client
Joe      Sub
Brian    Manager
```

Now I need to get all the titles, so I want to get:

```
Client
Manager
Sub
```

I know that there is `rs.Filter`, but I'm not sure if I can select distinct from it.

Also I know that I can clone this Recordset:

```
Dim rs_clone As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs_clone = New ADODB.Recordset
rs_clone = rs.getrows()
```

Is it possible to clone only distinct records? Or any better way? Thanks

Comment: is this legal in vba `Dim rs_clone As ADODB.Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset` ? Ok in vb.net but not sure if you can assign variable and instantiate in one line of `VBA`

Comment: You right, I just typed it here, but the idea is clear.

Comment: I'm sorry=) Will never do it again=)

Comment: `rs_clone = rs.getrows()` doesn't seem to work on my Excel either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firing a sql string at the database gives you lots of room to be very selective about what you'd like returned

Small example (using late binding which I prefer in production code) where I'm asking for a distinct list from the table column `MyColumn`

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 0

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn


'=====================
rs.Open "SELECT Distinct MyColumn AS C FROM myTable"
```

`strConn` needs to be set to the correct connection string.

---

**EDIT**

Without being able to fire a `sql` string at the database with the help of this post [vba: get unique values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array) I've got the following solution.

If you prefer early binding then references to the following will be required:

- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (Im using 6.1 library)
- Microsoft Scripting runtime (this is so we can use a dictionary)

Code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Global Const strConn As String = _
    "PROVIDER=MySQLprovider;" & _
    "P*SSWORD=MyPword;" & _
    "USER ID=MyLogin;" & _
    "INITIAL CATALOG=MyDB;" & _
    "DATA SOURCE=MyServer;" & _
    "USE PROCEDURE FOR PREPARE=1;" & _
    "AUTO TRANSLATE=True;"


Sub getDistinctRecords()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cn.Open strConn

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.ActiveConnection = cn

'>>this mimics your record set with non-distinct members
rs.Open _
    "SELECT 'a' as MyCol UNION ALL " & _
    "SELECT 'a' as MyCol UNION ALL " & _
    "SELECT 'b' as MyCol UNION ALL " & _
    "SELECT 'b' as MyCol"

Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = rs.GetRows() 

Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
    d(Arr(0, i)) = 1
Next i

Dim v As Variant
For Each v In d.Keys()

    '>>d.Keys() is a Variant array of the unique values in myArray.
    '>>v will iterate through each of them.

    '>>to print to the immediate window
    Debug.Print v
Next v

'=====================
     'tidy up connection
On Error Resume Next
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
    If (rs.State And 1) = 1 Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
If Not (cn Is Nothing) Then
    If (cn.State And 1) = 1 Then cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @KarlRookey it helps avoid version issues.

Comment: @ckuhn203 - so is this a general statement for all object variables, or just for working with database objects? I have always tried to early bind since it is faster, but I think I hear you and whytheq saying you would take a performance hit to make version compatibility issues less likely. Is that correct?

Comment: @KarlRookey it's a general statement. Late binding reduces the infamous "Missing Reference" when working with vba. Particularly in a situation where different users are using different versions of software. (Say Office 2003 & Office 2010). Here are a couple of links with more info on the topic. [Early vs. Late](http://stackoverflow.com/q/367411/3198973), this one over at [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/200130), and [What is early & late binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581/3198973)

Comment: @ckuhn203 easy enough to use early binding initially so you have intellisense etc. then once happy with code and all running ok I believe it is good to then convert to late binding

Comment: @Bryuk what do you mean by "In my case I MUST do it in code" ? Are you  unable to fire a sql string at the database using the `DISTINCT` operator ?