# What are the advantages of late binding? Give one example in context of function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, late-binding

Firstly, let me clarify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367411/early-binding-vs-late-binding-what-are-the-comparative-benefits-and-disadvanta) question doesn't explain my doubt clearly. To set the context clear. I'm asking this question specifically with regard to function pointers in C/C++.

I know the difference between early binding and late binding and how it works. What I would like to understand is the following with one example using function pointers in C/C++:

In many textbooks, it has been mentioned :

> advantage of late binding is that it is more flexible than early
>   binding, because decisions about what function to call do not need to
>   be made until run time.

Also, it mentions:

> With late binding, the program has to read the address held in the
>   pointer and then jump to that address. This involves one extra step,
>   making it slightly slower.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Add(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX + nY;
}

int Subtract(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX - nY;
}

int Multiply(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX * nY;
}

int main()
{
    int nX;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> nX;

    int nY;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> nY;

    int nOperation;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter an operation (0=add, 1=subtract, 2=multiply): ";
        cin >> nOperation;
    } while (nOperation < 0 || nOperation > 2);

    // Create a function pointer named pFcn (yes, the syntax is ugly)
    int (*pFcn)(int, int);

    // Set pFcn to point to the function the user chose
    switch (nOperation)
    {
        case 0: pFcn = Add; break;
        case 1: pFcn = Subtract; break;
        case 2: pFcn = Multiply; break;
    }

    // Call the function that pFcn is pointing to with nX and nY as parameters
    cout << "The answer is: " << pFcn(nX, nY) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

here, there is no advantage of using late binding and early binding as in the example below should be preferred.

```
int nResult = 0;
switch (nOperation)
{
    case 0: nResult = Add(nX, nY); break;
    case 1: nResult = Subtract(nX, nY); break;
    case 2: nResult = Multiply(nX, nY); break;
}

cout << "The answer is: " << nResult << endl;
```

Could someone explain with an easy example like below where **late binding is advantageous** and why should someone choose it over early binding?

Comment: One example is adding a plugin at runtime. How about embedding an Excel spreadheet in a Word document and being able to edit it from Word. In fact, you could invent a document format, an application to edit it and Word could late-bind to your program and people coulld  use it. These are examples of late binding. If you see an advantage or not, that is up to you.

Comment: I'm asking specifically w.r.t **function pointers in C/C++**. Could someone please remove the hold and try to answer?

Comment: What makes you think late binding is related to `function pointers in C/C++`? It's not. See for example [How To Use Visual C++ to Access DocumentProperties with Automation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238393) - that's `C++` code automating MS Word using late binding, and there is no `function pointer` used or needed.

Comment: @dxiv I agree with you completely. But I'm trying to understand it through a programming language that I know. I thought it would be easy to explain through function pointers. Wouldn't it? Is it too hard to explain in the context of using function pointers?

Comment: @VivekVijayan Still not sure what you mean by `in the context of using function pointers`. Just as an example, late binding in Windows OLE/COM essentially boils down to [IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306.aspx) and [IDispatch::Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx). Neither uses function pointers, and I wouldn't know how to explain them `in the context of using function pointers`. You'll need to frame your question better (and perhaps more narrowly) since it's not at all clear what you are after.

Comment: @dxiv Does this edit make it any clear? I just meant that function pointers could be used to show late-binding. Virtual functions are good examples of late-binding / runtime polymorphism too.

Comment: @VivekVijayan The sample code you just edited in is what I'd call *an indirect call via a function pointer*. I've never seen it called `late binding`. Maybe you should mention what `textbooks` you are referring to, since I don't think that's too common a usage. As for the question itself, suppose you replace the "*perform operation on nX, nY and return result*" task with "*round nX, nY to nearest multiples of 100, perform operation, then round result to nearest multiple of 100*". Try writing the latter with vs. without the function pointer - the former would be far simpler and more clear code.

Comment: @VivekVijayan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I'm going to skip over the whole "early binding vs late binding" definition question and pretend you asked "why would someone use function pointers instead of a switch statement?"

Because function pointers are more flexible. They aren't *static.* Let's take the business end of your code:

```
int InvokeOperation(int nOperation, int nX, int nY)
{
    switch (nOperation)
    {
        case 0: return Add(nX, nY);
        case 1: return Subtract(nX, nY);
        case 2: return Multiply(nX, nY);
    }
}
```

That's nice and functional. But it's not *flexible*. Why? Because all of the functions that can be called are defined by `InvokeOperation`; if you want to add a new operation, you have to be able to change `InvokeOperation`.

By contrast, if you used function pointers, you can build a whole registry of operations:

```
using Func = int(*)(int, int);
struct Op{Func func; std::string name;};
std::vector<Func> funcs =
{
    {&Add, "Add"},
    {&Subtract, "Subtract"},
    {&Multiply, "Multiply"},
};

int InvokeOperation(int nOperation, int nX, int nY)
{
    return funcs[nOperation].func(nX, nY);
}
```

Now, if you want to add more operations, just insert elements into `funcs`. If `InvokeOperation` were part of some library, you wouldn't necessarily have the right to change it. With static binding, you would have an inflexible system; what it supports is what it will *always* support.

With dynamic binding, you can add whatever stuff you want, whether you have the right to modify the library directly or not.