# Loose late binding v. strict late binding

Tags: python, language-design, late-binding, free-variable

While reading Python’s [Execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.htm%5D) documentation, I realized that Python’s free variables do not seem to have a strict *late binding* property where a name binding occurring in *any* code block can be used for name resolution. Indeed, executing:

```py
def f():
    return x

def g():
    x = 0
    return f()

print(g())
```

raises:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

They have rather a loose *late binding* property where only a name binding occurring in an *outer* code block of the code block introducing the free variable can be used for name resolution. Indeed executing

```py
def f():
    return x

x = 0
print(f())
```

prints:

```
0
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks of the loose late binding property compared to the strict late binding property?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367411/early-binding-vs-late-binding-what-are-the-comparative-benefits-and-disadvanta#:~:text=Traditionally%20the%20big%20advantage%20of,some%20optimizations%20at%20compile%20time.

Comment: Are you referring to [dynamic versus lexical/static scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping)?

Comment: Note that one can always emulate dynamic scoping, either by carrying around the namespace or contextualising a global namespace (see e.g. [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) and [threading.local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.local)).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Exactly! I cannot believe I had never heard about that fundamental concept before! That clears up so many things in my head. The entire article is a gem. Thanks so much. It even defines early binding as static scoping and late binding as dynamic scoping. So I incorrectly used the term late binding for Python since it has static scoping. Could you write an answer, I will gladly accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generally known as [*dynamic scoping* and *static scoping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping). Roughly speaking, dynamic scoping determines scope by *call nesting* and static scoping determines scope by *declaration nesting*.

In general, dynamic scoping is very easy to implement for any language with a call stack – a name lookup simply searches the current stack linearly. In contrast, static scoping is more complex, requiring several distinct scopes with their own lifetime.

However, static scoping is generally easier to understand, since the scope of a variable never changes – a name lookup has to be resolved *once* and will always point to the same scope. In contrast, dynamic scoping is more brittle, with names being resolved in different or no scope when calling a function.

---

Python's scoping rules are mainly defined by [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) introducing nested scoping ("closures") and [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) introducing writable nested scoping (`nonlocal`). The primary use-case of such *static scoping* is to allow higher-order functions ("function-producing-function") to automatically parameterise inner functions; this is commonly used for callbacks, decorators or factory-functions.

```py
def adder(base=0):  # factory function returns a new, parameterised function
    def add(x):
        return base + x  # inner function is implicitly parameterised by base
    return add
```

Both PEPs codify how Python handles the complications of static scoping. In specific, scope is resolved *once* at compile time – every name is thereafter strictly either global, nonlocal or local. In return, *static scoping allows to optimise variable access* – variables are read either from [a fast array of locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST), [an indirecting array of closure cells](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF), or a slow global dictionary.

An artefact of this statically scoped name resolution is `UnboundLocalError` : a name may be *scoped* locally but not yet *assigned* locally. Even though there is *some* value assigned to the name *somewhere*, static scoping forbids accessing it.

```py
>>> some_name = 42
>>> def ask():
...     print("the answer is", some_name)
...     some_name = 13
...
>>> ask()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'some_name' referenced before assignment
```

Various means exist to circumvent this, but they all come down to the programmer having to explicitly define how to resolve a name.

---

While Python does not natively implement dynamic scoping, it can in be easily emulated. Since dynamic scoping is identical to a stack of scopes for each stack of calls, this can be implemented explicitly.

Python natively provides [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.local) to contextualise a variable to each call stack. Similarly, [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) allows to explicitly contextualise a variable – this is useful for e.g. `async` code which sidesteps the regular call stack. A naive dynamic scope for threads can be built as a literal scope stack that is thread local:

```py
import contextlib
import threading


class DynamicScope(threading.local):  # instance data is local to each thread
    """Dynamic scope that supports assignment via a context manager"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('_scopes', [])  # keep stack of scopes

    @contextlib.contextmanager  # a context enforces pairs of set/unset operations
    def assign(self, **names):
        self._scopes.append(names)  # push new assignments to stack
        yield self                  # suspend to allow calling other functions
        self._scopes.pop()          # clear new assignments from stack

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        for sub_scope in reversed(self._scopes):  # linearly search through scopes
            try:
                return sub_scope[item]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        raise NameError(f"name {item!r} not dynamically defined")

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise TypeError(f'{self.__class__.__name__!r} does not support assignment')
```

This allows to globally define a dynamic scope, to which a name can be `assign`ed for a restricted duration. Assigned names are automatically visible in called functions.

```py
scope = DynamicScope()

def print_answer():
    print(scope.answer)  # read from scope and hope something is assigned

def guess_answer():
    # assign to scope before calling function that uses the scope
    with scope.assign(answer=42):
        print_answer()

with scope.assign(answer=13):
    print_answer()  # 13
    guess_answer()  # 42
    print_answer()  # 13
print_answer()      # NameError: name 'answer' not dynamically defined
```

Comment: Thanks for the PEP 227 reference and the dynamic scope emulation bonus! There is only one thing that I didn’t get: "An artefact of this statically scoped name resolution is `UnboundLocalError`" Javascript behaves the same. However C++ and Scheme are also statically scoped but they don’t raise unbound local variable errors for functions using a name bound in an enclosing block but bound later in the local block. It is good that you mention this, because I asked the question this morning in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63337235/2326961): what is the motivation for variable hoisting?

Comment: I will write an answer to the question if I can dig up some reliable sources.

Comment: Unfortunately they closed my post so you cannot write an answer anymore (even though it has 3 upvotes and 2 bookmarks so it is not like nobody is interested)… But I will open a new one for you when your answer is ready, because I am very interested in knowing the rationale. Or maybe you have the power to reopen it.

Comment: I asked the question about the motivation for variable hoisting on the official Python forum and finally Guido himself gave the rationale. If you are interested, the post is [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-does-python-have-variable-hoisting-like-javascript/4944).

Comment: Is there an easier way to handle update assignments? e.g. I need to do `scope.assign(flop_count=0)`, then `my_count = scope.flop_count + 10`, then `scope.assign(flop_count=my_count)`, because I can not just do `scope.flop_count += 10`

Comment: @SkyWalker You can do ``with scope.assign(flop_count=scope.flop_count + 10):``. You can alternatively treat the current scope as mutable by changing ``__setattr__``, so ``scope.flop_count += 10`` would work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you! yes, I've just implemented the later choice which is syntactically more appealing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi another thing, can we not switch to use a dict instead of a list for the scopes? I dont really understand how the `def assign(self, **names)` bit works if I switch over to a dict instead of a list ... because the implementation is doing a `self.__scopes.append(names)`

Comment: @SkyWalker It's a stack of namespaces, so a "list of dictionaries" – I don't see how a "flat dictionary" or "dictionary of dictionaries" could express this.

Answer (score -3):

**Static (Early) and Dynamic (Late) Binding :**

Binding refers to the association of names in program text to the storage locations to which they refer. In static binding, this association is predetermined at build time. With dynamic binding, this association is not determined until run-time.

Dynamic binding is the binding which happens in Python. This means that the Python interpreter does binding only as code runs. For example -

```
>>> if False:
...     x  # This line never runs, so no error is raised
... else:
...     1 + 2
...
3
>>>
```

**Advantages of dynamic binding**

- Main advantage of dynamic type binding is flexibility. It is more easy to write generic code.

  - Ex - a program to process a list of data in a language that uses dynamic type binding can be written as a generic program.

**Disadvantages of dynamic binding**

- Error detection capability of the compiler is diminished. some errors that a compiler could have caught.
- considerable overhead at runtime.

Comment: Sorry but you are talking about typing which is an entirely different topic from binding.