# How to nest two context managers at the implementation?

Tags: python

I have a bit of an odd use-case. I already have a context manager for all my CLI applications which provides a lot of useful non-functional concern tasks (e.g. config parsing, logging setup, response time calculation, etc), I call it `BaseCLI` as follows:

```
class BaseCLI(object):

   def __enter__(self):
       # ... a lot of stuff 
       return config

   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
       # exit implementation
```

I also have a `DynamicScope` implementation similar to the one in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340335/1142881. I would like to plug a dynamic scope instance to be reused as part my existing `BaseCLI` to do FLOP counting ... how can I do that? The `DynamicScope` is also a context manager and ideally I would like to do:

```
from somewhere import myscope

with BaseClI(...) as config:
   with myscope.assign(flop_count=0):
       # ... count the flops in every inner scope
```

This I would need to do in every CLI instance and that's not ideal .. I would instead like to achieve the same effect from the `BaseCLI` `__enter__` implementation but don't know how ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , maybe something like this?

```py
class BaseCLI(object):

   def __init__(self, scope, ...):
       self._scope = scope

   def __enter__(self):
       self._scope.__enter__()
       # ... a lot of stuff 
       return config

   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
       self._scope.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
       # exit implementation
```

```
from somewhere import myscope
with BaseCLI(myscope.assign(flop_count=0),...) as config
```

This will create the scope, and run it's _*enter*_ and _*exit*_ methods together with the BaseCLI class

Comment: I get the error that `self._scope` doesn't have an `__enter__()` attribute.